# Linear regression with two independent variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, statistics, regression

The following will output the `slope`, `intercept` and correlation coefficient `R^2` for a given set of `x` and `y` values.

```
let linearRegression = (y,x) => {
        let lr = {}
        let n = y.length
        let sum_x = 0
        let sum_y = 0
        let sum_xy = 0
        let sum_xx = 0
        let sum_yy = 0

        for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

            sum_x += x[i]
            sum_y += y[i]
            sum_xy += (x[i]*y[i])
            sum_xx += (x[i]*x[i])
            sum_yy += (y[i]*y[i])
        } 

        lr['slope'] = (n * sum_xy - sum_x * sum_y) / (n*sum_xx - sum_x * sum_x)
        lr['intercept'] = (sum_y - lr.slope * sum_x)/n
        lr['r2'] = Math.pow((n*sum_xy - sum_x*sum_y)/Math.sqrt((n*sum_xx-sum_x*sum_x)*(n*sum_yy-sum_y*sum_y)),2)

        return lr
}
```

How can I adapt this to accept two independent variables `x1, x2` rather than one?

This page goes into the modified formulas:

http://faculty.cas.usf.edu/mbrannick/regression/Reg2IV.html

But i've been struggling to adapt this to the above function.

Answer (score 0):

Step-by-step

First, look at the input line:
`let linearRegression = (y,x) => {`. You have 2 variables, so we could call them x1 and x2: `let linearRegression = (y,x1,x2) => {`

Now the formulae for the regression depend on dot products between the pairs of variables - x1.x1, x1.x2, x1.y etc.

So instead of calculating `sum_xx`, `sum_xy`, `sum_yy`, we need to calculate the sums for all of those pairs (with 3 variables instead of 2, there are 6 sums to calculate).

Finally, the two-variable equation is `y=a + b1.x1 + b2.x2`, so there are 2 slopes to calculate rather than 1, and the page you linked to gives all the formulae you would need there.